# mysql select count(column) where sum(column) > value

Tags: mysql, wordpress

I'm trying to query $wpdb to get back an int value of the number of users in a custom table who have recorded a number of hours volunteer work above a set target - these hours need to have been moderated ( value set to = 1 ) - I have this so far:

**EDIT** - updated to use consistent {} around php variables in query --

```
$target = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'target', true) ? (int)get_post_meta($post->ID, 'target', true) : 100;

$awards = $wpdb->get_var("
    SELECT user_id 
    FROM {$this->options['rewards_logging']} 
    WHERE moderated = 1 AND reward_id = {$post->ID} 
    GROUP BY user_id 
    HAVING sum(hours) > {$target}
");
```

Which returns the correct value of '0' if none of the hours are approved ( moderated = 0 ), however as soon as one of those users hours are approved, this query returns the count of all the users who have logged more than the target hours ( whether they have been approved or not ).

Any pointers!

Cheers

Ray

Comment: I am a little rusty on PHP, but how come your PHP variables are part of the string?

Comment: looks like there is nothing wrong with the query.

Comment: @SergueiFedorov, you can use `"{ $var->anything() }"`, it's curly braces.

Comment: the query return 0 if no users have moderated hours over the target - but as soon as 1 user has hours over the target moderated ( value == 1 ) then the query return the total count of users who have logged hours over the target ( ignoring the moderated column ) - I need to get that included in the logic of HAVING...

Comment: something like -> HAVING sum(hours) > {$target} AND moderated = 1 AND reward_id = {$post->ID} - not sure if that's possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems I was trying to get back a single variable using $wpdb->get_var, when I really needed the whole result set:

```
$awards = $wpdb->get_results("
     SELECT user_id
     FROM {$this->options['rewards_logging']} 
     WHERE moderated = 1 AND reward_id = {$post->ID} 
     GROUP BY user_id
     HAVING sum(hours) > {$target}
");
```

Then I can check over the data and display a result - etc...:

```
if ( count($awards) > 0 ) {

     #var_dump($awards);
     echo '<span class="awards-notice">'.count($awards).'</span>';
} else {
     echo '-';
}
```